# jaxb XML, not throwing exception when XML's integer value is > Java Long's Max Value

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, javax.xml

Say I'm trying to unmarshal an XML file with an integer field (xs:integer):
 13131546456131653154156415616

This value is > Java Long's max value.

I was hoping to get and catch an exception when Jaxb tried to unmarshal it.

Instead, there is no exception, and my pojo's object.Value is set to null.

Is there a way to detect when this happens and log it?

I've tried using vec, but it caught nothing (empty list):

```
    ValidationEventCollector vec = new ValidationEventCollector();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyPojo.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(vec);
    System.out.println(vec.getEvents().length);
   MyPojo model = (MyPojo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Answer (score 2):

[`xs:integer`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#integer) is not limited, it can be values of any length.
The comparable Java type is `BigInteger`.

[`xs:int`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#int) is however constrained to:

> ```
> maxInclusive = 2147483647
> minInclusive = -2147483648
> ```

And [`xs:long`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#long) is constrained to:

> ```
> maxInclusive = 9223372036854775807
> minInclusive = -9223372036854775808
> ```

So if you want the XML Schema Validator to check the value ranges, use the appropriate type.